# Common Words List

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm constantly having to backtrack over my project when I want to change a common term or word that is used

I know the solution is to have some of Language File, but not sure how to best handle that.  I was going to do it via the DB, but something tells me that is not the best way to achieve this

How is the above best accomplished?

Comment: I would probably have a file with all the string declarations, then import that file and use those constant variables or something, I dont know much ruby.

Answer (score 2):

Does this help?
Ruby internationalization
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html